# Oracle Dynamic delete statements with DECODE Function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Hi I have the following procedure:

```
create or replace procedure 
SP_DELETE_FROM_TABLE(pTableName in VARCHAR2, pFieldName in VARCHAR2,
                     pFieldValue in VARCHAR2,pFieldType in VARCHAR2) is

     querystring VARCHAR2(500);
begin
   queryString := 'DELETE FROM ' ||pTableName|| 
                 ' WHERE '||pFieldName ||' = DECODE(:pFieldType,integer,:pFieldValue)' ;


 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryString USING pFieldType,pFieldValue;

end SP_DELETE_FROM_TABLE;
```

all my Parameters are of Type VARCHAR2, What I am trying to do is: When I call the procedure with the following values ('users_table','users_id','11','integer')

so by using DECODE I would like to check if pFieldValue is of type pFieldTypeand if yes return pFieldValue

so if  pFieldValue is:11 and pfieldType is:integer it should delete users_id 11 if fieldType is string  do nothing..

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a function that checks parameter has correct type
and then use it in main procedure

```
--main procedure
create or replace procedure SP_DELETE_FROM_TABLE(pTableName in VARCHAR2, pFieldName in VARCHAR2,pFieldValue in VARCHAR2,pFieldType in VARCHAR2) is

querystring VARCHAR2(500);
begin

 if 'Y' = is_type_correct(pFieldValue, pFieldType )  then    
   queryString := 'DELETE FROM ' ||pTableName|| ' WHERE '
       ||pFieldName ||' =  :pFieldValue';

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryString USING pFieldValue;
 end
 else
    null; --incorrect type and parameter, do nothing
 end;

end SP_DELETE_FROM_TABLE;

--check function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_type_correct( p_val IN VARCHAR2, p_type varchar2 )
  RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC PARALLEL_ENABLE
IS
  l_num NUMBER;
  l_date date;
BEGIN
  if 'integer' = p_type 
  then 
    l_num := to_number( p_val );
  elsif 'date' = p_type then 
    l_date := to_date(p_val, 'YYYY.MM.DD');
  elsif 'varchar2' then
    null;//do nothing
  else
    return 'N'; //uknown type
  end if;

  RETURN 'Y';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN value_error THEN
    RETURN 'N';
END is_number;
```

Comment: I came up with this->    queryString := 'DELETE FROM ' ||pTableName|| ' WHERE '||pFieldName || '= DECODE(:pFieldType,
                                                                                       ''n'',to_number(:pFieldV1),
                                                                                       ''c'',to_char(:pFieldV2)
 )' ;

But When I add to_date it does not work.. is there any fix for this?

Comment: it missing `then` after `elsif`

Answer (score 0):

Just try to convert a string to a number, and when an exception occurs, do nothing:

```
     querystring VARCHAR2(500);
     some_number number;
begin
     some_number := to_number( pFieldValue ); /* trying to convert to a number */
     queryString := 'DELETE FROM ' ||pTableName|| 
                    ' WHERE '||pFieldName ||' = :x' ;


     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryString USING some_number;
EXCEPTION  
    WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN null; /* do nothing when pFieldValue is not a number*/
end SP_DELETE_FROM_TABLE;
```